# How do I set programmatically @Html.TextBoxFor type date in jquery, asp.net mvc 4

Tags: jquery, date, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this razor @Html.TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate, new { @class="form-control", @id="txtMyDate", @type = "date", Value = Model.MyDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")})
```

My problem is TextBoxFor not display the Model.MyDate, so How do I set this input in jquery programmatically, I tried this in jquery and not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#txtMyDate").val('@Model.MyDate');
});
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
My Solution:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate, new {@class = "form-control", @id = "txtMyDate", @type = "date", @Value = Model.MyDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")})
```

Comment: Its not clear what your trying to do. First you never set the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods (and its not clear why you want to change the `id` from MyDate to txtMyDate). Your code to generate the control should be `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: But if your want to generate the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (not supported in all browsers), then  the format needs to be `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO format).

Comment: The code will then be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" })`. No javascript is required (and all it was doing was setting it the the value it already was anyway)